# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component [Switch statement]

Tags: reactjs

When trying to run the code below i continue to receive the following error: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

I've indicated in the code where the error appears to exit but i'm not sure I understand the above error and am looking for guidance on how i can fix this. Is this stating that I need to include the onSubmit in a useEffect? TIA

```
export default function RegisterForm() {
  const { isAuth } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [serverError, setServerError] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [registerStep, setRegisterStep] = useState('register');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const unmounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      unmounted.current = true;
    };
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    dispatch(attemptRegister(values))
      .then(() => {
        if (!unmounted.current) {
          setEmail(values.email);
          setRegisterStep('resend');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          setServerError(error.response.data.message);
        }
      });
  };

  const onResendEmail = () => {
    dispatch(attemptResendConfirmation(email))
      .then(() => {
        if (!unmounted.current) {
          setRegisterStep('reset');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response) {
          setServerError(error.response.data.message);
        }
      });
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    dispatch(attemptResetRegister(email)).catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        setServerError(error.response.data.message);
      }
    });
  };

  function RenderSwitch() {
    switch (registerStep) {
      case 'register':
        return (
          ...
        );
      case 'resend':
        return (
          ...
        );

      case 'reset':
        return (
          ...
        );
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  return isAuth ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <RenderSwitch />;
}
```

Comment: It is just a guess but I think your isAuth variable might be changing while some of your requests are still running, so react is complaining that you need to abort that using the useEffect cleanup return

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you remove a component from the DOM while it is still doing something like waiting for a promise to resolve.

As soon as isAuth becomes true, the fragment with your renderSwitch() unmounts.  Likewise when the value of registerStep changes, the component previously returned from the switch statement unmounts.

You’re probably still waiting on one of your promises when this happens.  The error message tells you that you can use a useEffect cleanup to cancel the subscription, but probably you don’t want to be cancelling it.  What you want is to not unmount that part of the logic.

So rework your isAuth ternary and your switch statement such that you can return the UI you want while allowing the logic functions to continue execution.

Comment: Would you suggest doing this with the useRef to see if it is mounted or not and wrapping each step in an if statement? I've updated the code with what I figured would work, but im still getting the error.

Comment: That feels backwards to me.  It’s more that you want to be sure that your conditions are right for determining what component to mount/unmount.  Like (isAuth && didCompleteSubmit) ? redirect to home : show form. So you’re making sure that everything in the form has completed before you unmount it.